# Split string at special character in bash

Tags: string, bash, ubuntu

I'm reading filenames from a textfile line by line in a bash script. However the the lines look like this:

```
/path/to/myfile1.txt 1
/path/to/myfile2.txt 2
/path/to/myfile3.txt 3
```

...

```
/path/to/myfile20.txt 20
```

So there is a second column containing an integer number speparated by space. I only need the part of the string before the space. 
I found only solutions using a "for-loop". But I need a function that explicitly looks for the " "-character (space) in my string and splits it at that point.

In principle I need the equivalent to Matlabs "strsplit(str,delimiter)"

Comment: Search about the `awk` command.

Comment: `echo "$string" | cut -d' ' -f1` would suffice. However, if you share your overall method of reading the file we may come up with something cleaner.

Comment: I never understood the awk command. Also solutions using "echo" are not useful since I need to assign the "cut-version" of the string to a new variable.

Comment: What would you do if your file path contains space?

Comment: Actually someone just deleted a working solution for a bash script: vidPath="$1"
newVidPath="${1// *}"
You are right this doesn't cover the case where there are spaces in the file name, but so far this is good for me :). No idea why the guy deleted his answer

Comment: @mcExchange I deleted it because [chepner's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30032747/171318) is doing a good job. It is a while loop where the splitting is done by `read` immediately. I can undelete my answer if you like, however, chepner's attempt should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to iterate trough each line of the file anyways, you can cut off everything behind the space with `bash`:

```
while read -r line ; do
    # bash string manipulation removes the space at the end
    # and everything which follows it
    echo ${line// *}
done < file
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are already reading the file with something like

```
while read -r line; do
```

(and [you should be](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)), then pass *two* arguments to `read` instead:

```
while read -r filename somenumber; do
```

`read` will split the line on whitespace and assign the first field to `filename` and any remaining field(s) to `somenumber`.

Comment: This is going to become stressing when there are more than one number column after the string column...

Comment: Do you care about the numbers? If a line looks like `/path/to/file1.txt 3 4 5 6`, then `filename` will be set to `/path/to/file1.txt` and `somenumber` will be set to `3 4 5 6`. The input is only split into as many fields as necessary to populate the arguments to `read`.

Comment: Ahh ok. Then it would indeed be useful

Answer (score 2):

Three (of many) solutions:

```
# Using awk
echo "$string" | awk '{ print $1 }'
# Using cut
echo "$string" | cut -d' ' -f1
# Using sed
echo "$string" | sed 's/\s.*$//g'
```

Comment: note they are not entirely equivalent: `cut -d' '` will stick to one space. If you want it to behave properly with multiple spaces, you firstly need to squeeze them with `tr -s ' '`.

Comment: You are right. However the author sayed "the space" and "the space character", thus I assumed it was only one space. There are solutions to this problem, not always equivalent solutions.

Comment: I guess I cannot use the "echo" command. The string is not hardcoded but comes from a list of strings and must be assigned to a variable, which I use later in the script. So I would need to assing the "cut-version" of the string to a new variable. How would I do that in a bashscript?

Comment: What do you mean by "list of strings"? A file? Here `$string` can also be a "text" (a list of strings separated by newlines).

Comment: Well, with the current `echo $string` this would fail. To keep new lines you need to quote the variable: `echo "$string"`.

Comment: @GHugo I mean I'm reading an ascii text file with "while read p;do ...here I need to manipulate / split the string stored in $p and assign it to a new variable... ;done < myAsciiFile.txt". I cannot assign a new string using "echo". In other words I need something like "string2=echo "$string1" | awk '{ print $1 }' " which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
line="${line% *}"
```

This cuts the string at it's last occurrence (from left) of a space. So it will work even if the path contains spaces (as long as it follows by a space at end).

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r line
do
   { rev | cut -d' ' -f2- | rev >> result.txt;  } <<< $line
done < input.txt
```

This solution will work even if you have spaces in your filenames.